# Update with Select in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I have records on column1 without a name "NoName". Some of those *names* exist on the same column and I'm trying to use *column2* to retrieve the *names* with the same reference as the "NoName" records in order to update them with the actual name.

Consider this simplified table:

```
|   name   |   ref   |
----------------------
|  NoName  |   001   |
|  Adam    |   002   |
|  NoName  |   002   |
|  John    |   001   |
|  Ryan    |   003   |
```

The end result should be this:

```
|   name   |   ref   |
----------------------
|  John    |   001   |
|  Adam    |   002   |
|  Adam    |   002   |
|  John    |   001   |
|  Ryan    |   003   |
```

What I have so far is:

```
UPDATE [Table] 
SET [Name] = s.[Name]
FROM (
      SELECT [Name], [Ref] 
      FROM [Table] as s
      WHERE [Name] <> 'NoName')
WHERE 
     [Name]='NoName' AND [Ref] = s.[Ref]"
```

Right now I'm getting an error saying:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 's.[Name] FROM (
>   SELECT [Name], [Ref]  FROM [Table] as s WHERE [Name] <> 'NoName')'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, MS Access uses `UPDATE...JOIN` as its syntax and not `UPDATE...FROM` for multiple tables in `UPDATE` queries. Second, Access requires update queries to be [*updateable*](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-61.html) where self-joins or subqueries are not updateable.

However, you can use domain function, `DLookUp`, to retrieve values from same table:

```
UPDATE [Table] t
SET t.[Name] = DLookUp("[Name]", "[Table]", 
                       "[Name] <> 'NoName' AND [Ref] = '" & t.[Ref] & "'")
```

Note: this solution will only work if using query inside MSAccess.exe (Office program) and not its backend database via ODBC/OLEDB. [Domain functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/application-dlookup-method-access) are part of hte Access object library and not the Jet/ACE SQL Engine. And *Ref* is assumed to be a string value.

Comment: I'm accessing it through a DAO connection. The code looks something like this: `OpenDatabase(FullPath).Execute SQL`

Comment: But you are running inside MSAccess.exe? If so, it should work. Did you try solution?

Comment: I'm running inside Excel, not in Access.

Comment: `UPDATE...JOIN` is way to go in this case, correct?

Comment: Again, did you try it? DAO is an Access object so may allow for it. And again, for `UPDATE...JOIN` you would be joining on a self-join or subquery which is no *updateable*. Hence, the `DLookUp` route.

Comment: Perfait! Thank you so much! I was struggling with this for almost two hours!

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help. Happy coding!